# Question about the Geometric Sequence Theorem

Tags: calculus

I am reading my professor's notes, and there is something that I'm not understanding about this. The Geometric Sequence Theorem states that if $r$ is a real number such that $|r| < 1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} r^n = 0$. I understand that well enough, but then she gives us an example that asks whether $(2^n/3^{n+1})$ is convergent.

She ends up writing:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to infty} (a_n)
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}} \\
&= \frac 1 3 \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^n}{3^n}
\end{align*}
and I'm wondering how in the WORLD she took a $1/3$ out of there.

Also, is the geometry sequence theorem basically stating that if $r$ is a fraction, then $r^n = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint --I don't have enough points for a comment:

$3^{n+1}=3(3^n)$ , so that $\frac {2^n}{3^{n+1}}$ =$\frac {2^n}{3.3^n}=....$

And, be careful; if r is a fraction with ratio *between -1 and 1* (non-inclusive), then

$r^n\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Hints can be perfectly good answers.

Comment: I don't know why my mind is not seeing it, but I don't get how $3^{n+1}=3(3^n)$

Comment: Perhaps you're forgetting basic exponents rules, @user98852. Remember that $$a^n\cdot a^m=a^{n+m}$$ and thus $\;3^{n+1}=3^n\cdot 3^1=3\cdot3^n\;$